# Remove the stuff up to and including the word in a string with multiple lines

Tags: linux, perl, shell

I have the following string with multiple lines. I cannot make it one line since it is coming from a command output. for e.g:

```
my $myString = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a 
type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also 
the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
It was popularised in the 1960s"
```

I want to strip off the stuff up to and including the word "scrambled"

I have tried below but does not seem to work.

```
if($myString =~ 's/.*(scrambled)//s')
{
  print "Match:   <$&>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $myString = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a 
type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also 
the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
It was popularised in the 1960s";

$myString =~ s/.*\bscrambled\b//s;

print $myString;
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/EHzxLU)

Comment: What about if the string contains `unscrambled`...? Better we will use `\bscrambled\b`.

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping quotes:

```
if($myString =~ s/.*(scrambled)//s)
```

With the quotes its trying to match the literal `s/.*(scrambled)//s`  without trying to change anything. Without the quotes the "s" substitute will be seen.

Answer (score -1):

> Use can use `pre` & `post`.

```
$myString =~ s/\bscrambled\b//ig && print $`.$';
```

> or else

```
if($myString =~ s/\bscrambled\b//s)
{
    print "Pre: <$`>\n";
    print "Match:   <$&>\n";
    print "Post:   <$'>\n";
}
```